# How to make constructor argument private?

Tags: javascript, class

Was wondering if it's possible to make the argument passed to the constructor below private? I tried wrapping in a function, but no success.. But basically, I shouldn't be able to change the value of `test.one` after a value is already set.

```
class Test {
  constructor(one){
    this.one = one;
  }

  log(){
    console.log(this.one);
  }
}

const test = new Test(1);

test.log();
```

Comment: "Making it private" and "Making it unchangeable" are two very different things. Which one do you want?

Comment: Please show us how you tried "wrapping it in a function", even if that didn't work we can help you to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use private instance fields using **# names** (hash names). In your case, it would be the following:

```js
class Test {
  #one

  constructor(one){
    this.#one = one;
  }

  log(){
    console.log(this.#one);
  }
}

const test = new Test(1);

test.log();
console.log(test.#one) // syntax error
```

Good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_instance_fields